# Парсинг веб сайта через сохранение angular.element($$).scope()

Tags: angularjs, vbscript, wsh

Сделал парсер сайта, но его вёрстка периодически меняется, а т.к. он использует теги и поиск по телу страницы, надо менять подход. В консоле chrome/ie легко получаю все данные через `angular.element($$).scope()`, но не знаю как сохранить эту информацию. Пробовал batarang, который удобно выводит все скопы, но как сохранить их не знаю.
Прошу подсказать, как используя простенький скрипт сохранять данные `angular.element($$).scope()` и вообще, в правильном направлении я двигаюсь?

PS: Мне подсказали использовать запросы напрямую к апи, но описания апи у меня нет, так что у меня не получилось.

Comment: Парсер сайта уже сделанный на vbs ? Откуда взялась эта метка ?

Comment: Парсер был сделан на vbs, но он раз в неделю перестаёт работать, т.к. использует обычные теги и поиск по телу страницы, по этому я и обратился. Эта метка взята с форумов и проверена в консоле браузера. Данные. которая она возвращает - ровно то, что мне надо, но как это сохранить для дальнейшего использования я не знаю.

Comment: А парсер был создан путем создания файла с расширением vbs и запускаемый в ОС Windows ? То есть Вы применяли [WSH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) ?

Comment: Да. он имел код, в виде:
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
OpenURL IE, URL
output = IE.document.getElementsByClassName(class).item().innertext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я плохо помню VBS, поэтому можете сделать порт с JS.

Копайте в этом направлении:

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.visible = true;
ie.Navigate( "https://portal.sf.mail.ru/error/HiddenFromAnonymous/user/avatar/720608925728415‌​16" );
while( ie.busy ) {
    WScript.sleep( 100 );
};

var win =  ie.document.parentWindow;    

WScript.echo( win.angular.element(win.$$).scope().$$destroyed );
```

Сохранив этот файл как `test.js` и запустив его в ОС Windows Вы увидите результат работы AngularJS.

Comment: Спасибо, пробую.

Comment: Выполнил код на JS, применительно к запрашиваемому сайту, но результат отличается от ожидаемого.
`var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.visible = true;
ie.Navigate( "https://portal.sf.mail.ru/error/HiddenFromAnonymous/user/avatar/72060892572841516" );
while( ie.busy ) {
    WScript.sleep( 100 );
};

WScript.echo( ie.document.parentWindow.$( "angular.element($$).scope().$$destroyed" ));
`
ангулар там уже подключен, запрашиваемый элемент вызывается через консоль IE, а вот скрипт возвращает null вместо содержащегося там false
Подскажите, где моя ошибка.

Comment: @Семён привел пример. В выводе 0, что означает false.

Comment: огромное спасибо! Это полностью решило мою проблему!